# "a symbol name was expected" error trying to create a table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a table in a database in phpMyAdmin and I keep getting the "a symbol name was expected" error and I cannot figure out what is going on.  Is my syntax wrong?  I am new to this and I'm at a loss.

[image: Create Table Query]

Comment: replace `'` with ` use single quote only for values and ` for columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names, table names should be surrounded by backticks(``` `` ```)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Or you can go without backticks as well:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sales (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    item varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   date varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   amount int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `' '` sign in your column properties. But `mySQL` allow you to use ``` `` ``` sign.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `item` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong , So here is the correct Code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `item` VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `amount` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```